# I have a PyCharm Professional Edition I use for work, does it log all the stuff I code in it?

Tags: pycharm

I have a PyCharm Professional Edition I was provided for work, does it log all the stuff I code in it? Because I'm also coding for a startup, I want to make sure when I use it it doesn't log what I used it for. or else I would use another editor.

I am working on my own pc by the way

Comment: What do you mean for "logging"? PyCharm will keep your changes locally (so you can go back and see what did you changed locally in last hours). But it should not log remotely (and in any case they will not care about your code). You may need to disable crash reporting, and usage statistics to be sure

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thank you! That helped!